# Cannot convert from Linq.JToken to Model

Tags: c#

I have a viewmodel that contains a list named "cards".

The list looks at another model which has several values, in my controller i am trying to loop through an array and pass each value into my ViewModel but am getting the above error.

```
var rest = JArray.Parse(responseString);
                foreach (var rec in rest[0]["team"][0]["cards"])
                {
                    //Pass the values into the viewmodel list
                    vm.Cards.Add(rec);
                }
```

Each 'rec' contains 4 values, but i am getting an error when i try and add them to my viewmodel(see title)

Any help would be great.

Comment: If your json data contains serialized viewmodels, you would need to deserialize the json (i.e. turn the json data into actual viewmodel instances), not just trying to stuff the "raw" json data into your vm.Cards collections. That said, it wouldn't really make sense to have viewmodels serialized in json, i guess; as usually you would serialize/deserialize data (data model), not view models; but it looks like that's what you are attempting to do, so i am just going along with that...

Comment: I'm getting this data from an external API, its a json array that has way more detail than i actually need, which is why i parsed it and trying to extract only one record into my model.

Comment: Yeah, okay. But the matter of fact remains that there is no json data type "Model", hence the error (there are only Json objects, json arrays, numbers, strings, and bools, i guess). Thus, you would need to create a `Model` instance from the json data and stuff this into your model collection `vm.Cards`...

Comment: I understand, so how do i pass values from the array into my model?

Comment: How would i know? You are asking me about your model(s) like i know anything about your model(s) or the structure of your json data... o_O?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `rec` from `JToken` to `Model`

```
vm.Cards.Add(rec.ToObject<Model>());
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, why this isnt exactly what i need, it has helped point me in the right direction.